# Как использовать оператор AND, если внутри выражения может быть null

Tags: mysql

Есть следующий запрос (обратите внимание на последние 2 строки с AND, мой вопрос о них):

```
SELECT type.object_id, type.term_taxonomy_id as type_id, industry.term_taxonomy_id as industry_id
FROM wp_term_relationships type 
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships industry ON type.object_id = industry.object_id 
WHERE type.object_id = industry.object_id 
AND type.term_taxonomy_id = $_GET['type'] 
AND industry.term_taxonomy_id = $_GET['industry'] // если здесь GET-параметр равен null, то этой строки не должно быть. То же самое, соответственно, и для строки выше
```

Ситуация такая, что какой-то из GET-параметров не всегда передается. И получается: $_GET['industry'] не передался, то последняя строка с AND будет выглядеть:
`AND industry.term_taxonomy_id = null`, и весь запрос покажет null. Мне же нужно, чтобы технически выглядело так: если не параметра, то и соответствующей строчки с AND нет. Благодарю за помощь!

P.s да, проблему можно решить при помощи тернарного выражения и конкатенации строк. Но этот вопрос задается исключительно ради ликбеза и хочется решить только SQL-запросом.

Comment: `AND column = COALESCE($_GET[parameter], column)`

Comment: @Akina, а если переданы оба get-параметра? COALESCE возвращает первое не-null значение

Comment: И чё? всё равно во WHERE они тестируются по отдельности.

Comment: @Akina, null выводится

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT type.object_id, type.term_taxonomy_id as type_id, industry.term_taxonomy_id as industry_id
FROM wp_term_relationships type 
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships industry ON type.object_id = industry.object_id 
WHERE type.object_id = industry.object_id 
AND IF($_GET['type'] IS NOT NULL, type.term_taxonomy_id = $_GET['type'], 1)
AND IF($_GET['industry'] IS NOT NULL, industry.term_taxonomy_id = $_GET['industry'], 1)
```

Comment: Запрос выводит null, к сожалению.

Comment: я просто выше написал `$_GET['type'] = 13; $_GET['industry'] = null;` и запрос вернул пустой массив. Если же `$_GET['type'] = 13; $_GET['industry'] = 134;` - то массив с двумя значениями. Если убрать строчку в запросе с AND, где  $_GET['industry']` (типа параметр не передан), то массив с 70 значениями.